# Spring params is not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, http-request-parameters

Annotation with spring `params` is not working.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody ResponseMsg login(@RequestParam String userName, @RequestParam String password ) 
{
    ResponseMsg responseMsg = CommonUtils.checkParam(userName, password);

    if(responseMsg.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("True"))
    {
        responseMsg =  userService.login(userName, password);
    }
    return responseMsg;
}
```

I'm using this function for get value in put but it shows 400 Bad Request. Any help?

Comment: Can you post the link/javascript that calls this method?

Comment: localhost:8080/karmaFriend/login after that i put data in header like   username: kkk
password: kkk

Comment: Were you actually doing an HTTP PUT when you tested it, and not just trying to visit the URI with your browser?

Comment: What are typing in browser to call this controller? Also Double-chceck  the requestmethod will be with PUT option or POST option?

Comment: OK, I know the reason, you should change the parameter names to userName and password or follow my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

right ans is this ... and thx to    OQJF

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseMsg login(@RequestHeader(value="username", required=false) String userName, 
            @RequestHeader(value="password", required=false) String password ) {

        ResponseMsg responseMsg = CommonUtils.checkParam(userName, password);
        if(responseMsg.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("True"))
            responseMsg =  userService.login(userName, password);
        return responseMsg;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First use firebug to see what parameters that you send to controller. If the parameter names is correct. I think the reason is that the field annotated with @RequestParam that the default is required, it means that the parameters that sent from client must contains them which are userName and passWord, change to this :`@RequestParam(value="username" required=false) String userName, @RequestParam(value="password" required=false) String password` and try it.

Comment: but big thing is that i used @ RequestParam   i solved it using @RequestHeader

Comment: lol, buddy. the reason is not you use which annotation, It is because you didn't specify the value of annotation, 1 field name you use is userName, then by default, Spring will try to find a parameter which name is userName,but your parameter name is username, it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to use a post in this scenario.  But you could try accessing the header params as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody ResponseMsg login(@RequestHeader("username") String userName, @RequestHeader("password") String password ) {
                ResponseMsg responseMsg = CommonUtils.checkParam(userName, password);
                if(responseMsg.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("True"))
                    responseMsg =  userService.login(userName, password);
                return responseMsg;
            }
```

Comment: @krishan but in the post above you mention that you solved it with `@RequestHeader`